# Sound detection of noise not speech in Ionic - how?

Tags: cordova, audio, ionic-framework, detection

Anyone of you has an idea of how to implement a sound detection of different noises in Ionic?

I am currently working on an app (a game based on sound detection), that should be able to detect 3 different sounds and depending on which sound the app detects, it should display different things.

Right now I have no idea how to do that and I would be really thankful if someone knows a solution for that problem.

Comment: What sorts of sounds are you trying to detect? This might be a much more difficult problem than you imagine.

Comment: You have three pieces (with different materials inside) that you can shake and each piece makes a specific sound when you shake it: 1) Bells 2) Sand grains 3) Rocks - the app than should detect which piece you have shaked.

Comment: Huh. That could be easy, could be hard. Your first step is to try to determine the different qualities of the different sounds, for example, by spectral analysis.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will do that. So when the sounds are different enough it would make it easier, no? What would be the next step?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this: `cordova-plugin-dbmeter`
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/db-meter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with ionic. Ionic is an Angular framework that creates an container to run a website.

You should check it how to do it via C or [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/20033/) or Java etc.

Logic should be :

take wave, frequency and other variables of sound. Save your waves eg bells so you can compare them. Basically you will create SHAZAM.

Here is an example of it in Java: 
http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/

So no ionic :)

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer and the link to the example!

If I'm going for Java to detect the different sounds, do you know if there is a possibility to combine that with ionic? Right now I have created the UI of the app in ionic and now I'm stuck.

Comment: It will be so hard to do it on ionic, you have to develope so many cordova plugins for that. I dont want to say is not possible, but definitely not worth it.

Comment: Okay i get it. Thank you very much!